# JS/ES6 Reference a constant in map.get

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to use a constant instead of a key from a map as long as the constant's value equals a key from the map?

```
const myColor = 'dark';
const myMap = new Map();

myMap.set('dark', {
  primary: '#000',
});

const myValues: {
  first: myMap.get(myColor).primary,
}
                   ^ This should output to 'dark' and access the primary key.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a constant instead of a key from a map as long as the constant's value equals a key from the map?

Yes, you can use any variable as the key as long as its value is `===` to the original key.  `const` or no `const` does not make a difference for a `Map` key.

---

Also, in your `myValues` declaration, it should be this:

```
const myValues = {
  first: myMap.get(myColor).primary,
}
```

where you use `=` instead of `:`.

Comment: Ok, so that must not be my problem then, I'm getting a unexpected token error on the opening paren for `myColor`.

Comment: @Potter - Note, I added a note about a syntax error in your `myValues` declaration.

Comment: Ahh, yep the `=` was what I was missing! Thanks for you all your help.

Comment: @stephenway - Next time you post, you'd get more helpful and targeted responses right away if you include the actual error/problem you're trying to solve (in this case, the actual error you're getting).  Glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 1):

yes, your only problem is that your syntax is off.

```
const myColor = 'dark';
const myMap = new Map();

myMap.set('dark', {
  primary: '#000',
});

const myValues = {
  first: myMap.get(myColor).primary,
}
```

Comment: Thank you, missed typing out the string on the hex code. Updated the question.